# Max of $f^2$ in terms of max of $f$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Is it true that $\max(|f(x)|^2) = (\max |f(x)|)^2$? Where $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: It seems to me that you wrote an identity. Maybe $\max |f|^2 = (\max |f|)^2$?

Comment: do you mean $(\max |f(x)|)^2$?

Comment: Do you mean "$[\max(|f(x)|)]^2$"?

Comment: yes that's what i meant

Comment: Can someone explain why this is true please thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The map $x \mapsto x^2$ is bijective and strictly increasing from $[0,+\infty)$ onto itself.

Comment: That's great way of showing it. Thanks!!!!

Comment: wait so is it not true the statement??

Comment: I would say it is true.

Comment: could you explain your hint for me please i didn't get it.

Comment: If you have the largest number of a set, then its square will be the largest number of the squares of the elements of that set.